# Python File Search Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I recently wrote this script in Python 3.5 to search a text file for a given string, I can't seem to figure out how to have the script remove the rest of the words after the word "log" shows up in the line.

```
file1 = input ('What is the name of the file? ')
search_string = input ('What are you looking for? ')
with open(file1) as cooldude:
for line in cooldude:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if search_string in line:
        print(line)
```

An example would be:
"I want to keep this stuff. log I don't want this stuff."
I would want to remove everything after and including the word "log". Thanks!

Comment: What if a line contains the word "**log**ic" or "**log**arithm"? Or "ana**log**"?

Comment: The file(s) I would be searching would not have any of those words within the line.

Comment: so `line,sep,_ = line.partition('log')` or `line = line.split('log')[0]`

Comment: @M.T why did you write that as a comment, it's is a perfectly good answer :-)

Comment: @M.T thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to remove the part of the text after a pattern `'log'`  in a line, you could use either the first part of the output of [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) or the 0'th index of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> line = "I want to keep this stuff. log I don't want this stuff."

>>> line1,sep,_ = line.partition('log')
>>> line1
"I want to keep this stuff. "

>>> line2 = line.split('log')[0]
>>> line2  
"I want to keep this stuff. "
```

For a slight variation one could remove only the part after the last `'log'` using [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with `maxsplit=1`:

```
>>> line = "I want to keep this stuff. log log I don't want this stuff."
>>> line3 = line.rsplit('log',1)[0]
>>> line3
"I want to keep this stuff. log"
```